# How to make Serial instance from another one with permutations (simulation of "any order")

Tags: haskell, smallcheck

[SmallCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/smallcheck-1.1.5/docs/Test-SmallCheck-Series.html) related question.

If I wrote the instance `Series m [Something]` then how can I create `Series m Something` from it? This list appeared in the type because I have 4 series and I want to generate series of their permutations (aka IN ANY ORDER), so I used `Data.List.permutations` and I get the list as a result. So I have series of lists, I know that series can be united but I cannot understand how to use that fact. Also I can create `Series m (Series m SomethingElse)` but it looks even more complex. How to work with permutations in the case? How to convert them to simple `Series m Something`?